# Convert dataframe column values into a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named `matchdf`. It is a huge one so I'm showing the 1st 3 rows and columns of the dataframe:

`print(matchdf.iloc[:3,:3]`

```
   Unnamed: 0                                   athletesInvolved awayScore
0           0  [{'id': '39037', 'name': 'Azhar Ali', 'shortNa...         0
1           1  [{'id': '568276', 'name': 'Imam-ul-Haq', 'shor...         0
2           2  [{'id': '568276', 'name': 'Imam-ul-Haq', 'shor...         0
```

I was working with `athletesInvolved` column and as you can see it contains a list which is of form:

`print(matchdf['athletesInvolved'][0])`

```
[{'id': '39037', 'name': 'Azhar Ali', 'shortName': 'Azhar Ali', 'displayName': 'Azhar Ali'}, {'id': '17134', 'name': 'Tim Murtagh', 'shortName': 'Murtagh', 'displayName': 'Tim Murtagh'}]
```

However the datatype for this object is `str` as opposed to a `list`. How can we convert the above datatype to a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can using `ast`

```
import ast 
df.c=df.c.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: Can you please show how it can be used in context of above dataframe?

Comment: df. athletesInvolved=df.athletesInvolved.apply(ast.literal_eval) @ArohanAjit

Comment: sorry but its showing value error :( `ValueError: malformed node or string: nan`

Comment: @ArohanAjit try run my code with your sample data (3 row data), if that is work, then  you may need to find the different between the sample data and your real data